# Check for successful creation of records on create rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looping through a CSV and creating new records for each row.

How can I increment a counter if the creation of a record was successful?

Here is my existing code:

```
Employer.create(employer) do |e|
   e.password = generated_password
   e.tenant = tenant
end
```

I'd like to increment a counter like `i+=1` if the `.create` worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can inspect the returned instance to see if it was persisted or not:

```
employee = Employee.create(...) do |e|
   ...
end

i += 1 if employee.persisted?
```

You could also do this inside of the block.

Alternatively, separate this into separate new/save calls, and check the return value of `save`, which will be `true` or `false`.